# If not Opera Mini

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opera, opera-mini

This question is quite simple, but I want to ask it anyway.

This code tell us that user's browser is a famous **Opera Mini**

```
var isOperaMini = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1);
```

So I can use it in this way:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1)
    alert('hey! your browser is buggy');
```

This is `if Opera Mini, then` conditional.

How do I make a **right short conditional** for `if not Opera mini, then`?

I'm not sure how should I play with `-1` integer.

Comment: Actually, that code only tells you that the passed in user-agent header contains `Opera Mini`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

Comment: wow, _please_ do not implement boolean negation with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change it to

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') == -1)
```

That will return true if it does NOT find 'Opera Mini' in the user agent string

Comment: will it return `true` **only** in Opera Mini?

Comment: @Steve - It will return true if the user-agent does not contain `Opera Mini`. Looks like you really need to read about [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 3):

From the [Opera doc](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/):

> **Detecting Opera Mini**:
> 2 approaches: You can:
>
> 1. Examine the user agent string
> 2. Check for the presence of the operamini object

i.e. If not Opera Mini is:

`if (!window.operamini){}`

Short, easy and reliable. Unlike the spoof-able user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

Another options (maybe less readable) using `~` operator:

```
if (~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini')) {
    // opera mini
}

if (!~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini')) {
    // not opera mini
}
```

However it's probably better for you to compare with `-1`, until you are familiar with syntax.

Comment: Someone disagrees? Comments?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/

```
var isOperaMini = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]"
```